# Package nao_remote depends on non-existent package move_base_msgs

Tags: navigation, nao-robot, nao, rosmake, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm currently using ROS to remotely control a NAO robot. This is done with the `nao_robot` and `nao_common` stacks.

Suddenly I could not run the `pose_manager.py` in `nao_common/nao_remote/scripts`. It simply fails saying

> rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: move_base_msgs

I ran this a couple of days ago without problems.

To solve my problem I tried to run

> rosmake nao_remote

which fails saying

> [rosbuild] Building package nao_remote

> Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests nao_remote

> [rospack] Error: package/stack nao_remote depends on non-existent package move_base_msgs

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Isak

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55193/package-nao_remote-depends-on-non-existent-package-move_base_msgs/) by [I.T](https://answers.ros.org/users/4077/i.t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of any recent changes in nao_remote. Did you change anything in your ROS installation, removing packages from your installation or your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

By checking the [nao_remote wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao_remote), you will see that it depends on [move_base_msgs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base_msgs?distro=fuerte) which is in the navigation stack. Thus, you will need to install it with `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-navigation`, just like any stack containing packages that are a prerequisite for nao_remote.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [I.T](https://answers.ros.org/users/4077/i.t/) on 2013-02-14**:
This did the trick! I did not change anything in my installation on purpose so I still find it a bit weird. Thanks anyway!

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-02-14**:
You probably did not need the move_base_msgs if you only used a few nodes from nao_remote that's why it did not become apparent before. It could be that rospkg or rospack (in rosmake) now simply check the dependencies more strictly.